# React Native Picker not updating state

Tags: android, react-native, picker, setstate

I am developing a react native app. in that i am using picker to select item and update a state. M problem  is picker is not updating the state below is my code

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state=({
        category:'',
    })

    getPickerElements() {
        var pickerArr = [];
        data.forEach((child, itemIndex) => {
            pickerArr.push(<Picker.Item label={child.storeName} value={child.storeId} key={itemIndex}/>)
        })

        return pickerArr;
    }

    <Picker
        selectedValue={this.state.category}

        onValueChange={(itemvalue) =>{
            this.setState({category: itemvalue})
        }}>

        {/* -------------------Dynamic Picker Data------------------ */}
        {this.getPickerElements()}
        {/* -------------------------------------------------------- */}
    </Picker>
```

> For the record the 'data'  have data and drop down working properly

Comment: Also It seems your code is incomplete. Could you post a more complete sample?

Answer (score 2):

onValueChange requires change in values, in case of react native we need to provide a default value (selected value) which ,ight be options from our data, or just a label item . So that every other items when picked will invoke the onvaluechange methid.

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem with the native picker itself. i added only one item first. the first item will not  setState in react native android. when i add 2 item and select second one it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, I was retrieving data then setting the state of the selected values for all my pickers and it wasn't updating.
All my data items have this format: **{id: '',item: ''}**

I switched from this (doesn't update):

```
  const [elementSelected, SetElementSelected] = useState({id:0,item:''});
...
              <Picker
                selectedValue={elementSelected}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                  setElementSelected(itemValue)
                }>
                {data.map((val, key) => (
                  <Picker.Item label={val.item} value={val} key={key} />
                ))}
              </Picker>
```

to this:

```
  const [elementSelected, SetElementSelected] = useState({id:0,item:''});
...
              <Picker
                selectedValue={elementSelected.id}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                  setElementSelected(data[itemValue-1])
                }>
                {data.map((val, key) => (
                  <Picker.Item label={val.item} value={key} key={key} />
                ))}
              </Picker>
```

Notice that I changed the **selectedValue** to get the element id (int) and the Picker Item **value prop** to the key index. Now it works and sets the state. Weird but it works.